# Feature set out of grayscale Images for training a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, image-recognition, datasets, artificial-neuron

Previously I had trained a `Neural Network`upon 20,000 character images. This `Neural Net` generally works well, it uses `RGB- Hue, Saturation, Intensity` feature set for training. However, there can be certain character images which have `RGB-HSI` values that this `neural net` has not seen before. Therefore I am looking forward to converting training data to `grayscale` and use some feature set well suited for grayscale images.

So are there any good suggestion for extracting a feature set out of `grayscale` images.